my flutter app won't run gradle is throwing an error i installed sharedpreferences dependecy if i remove it the eeror will be gone
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:extractDebugAnnotations'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.3.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.0/kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar'.
> Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 40,346,136; received: 8,650,688)

it started when i installed sharedpreference package
if i remove it from the pubspec. it builds perfectly but if i put sharedpreferences it wont build

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can try these following steps.
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build <your-target>

Additionally you can refer this below link.
https://youtu.be/NCzi0_I05yY?si=K9WHsfXnwz5P9mCS
